# Having trouble understanding the Hopcroft-Karp algorithm for maximum matching

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Here's the pseudo-code for this algorithm ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)):

```
/*
 G = G1 ∪ G2 ∪ {NIL}
 where G1 and G2 are partition of graph and NIL is a special null vertex
*/

function BFS ()
    for v in G1
        if Pair_G1[v] == NIL
            Dist[v] = 0
            Enqueue(Q,v)
        else
            Dist[v] = ∞
    Dist[NIL] = ∞
    while Empty(Q) == false
        v = Dequeue(Q)
        if Dist[v] < Dist[NIL] 
            for each u in Adj[v]
                if Dist[ Pair_G2[u] ] == ∞
                    Dist[ Pair_G2[u] ] = Dist[v] + 1
                    Enqueue(Q,Pair_G2[u])
    return Dist[NIL] != ∞

function DFS (v)
    if v != NIL
        for each u in Adj[v]
            if Dist[ Pair_G2[u] ] == Dist[v] + 1
                if DFS(Pair_G2[u]) == true
                    Pair_G2[u] = v
                    Pair_G1[v] = u
                    return true
        Dist[v] = ∞
        return false
    return true

function Hopcroft-Karp
    for each v in G
        Pair_G1[v] = NIL
        Pair_G2[v] = NIL
    matching = 0
    while BFS() == true
        for each v in G1
            if Pair_G1[v] == NIL
                if DFS(v) == true
                    matching = matching + 1
    return matching
```

I'm trying to decide what each variable should be. It seems like `G1` and `G2` in the code start off as the same size as `G`, but they're initialized to `NIL`. However, in the BFS algorithm, what is `Adj[v]` exactly?  What would this be analogous to in a typical graph scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Adj[v]` means the adjacency list of `v` i.e. the list of its adjacent vertices. `G1` and `G2` are the partitions of the graph. As Hopcroft-Kapr algorithm is for bipartite graphs the solution suggests that the graph is partitioned in two partitions namely `G1` and `G2`.

Comment: If G1 and G2 are partitions, then how does this work:  for each v in G....Pair_G1[v] = NIL...Pair_G2[v] = NIL. Wouldn't this mean that G1 and G2 are identical in size to G?

Comment: `Pair_G1` and `Pair_G2` are some other helper arrays, different from `G1` and `G2`.

Comment: Oh, OK. Thank you! Do you know how the adjacency list is typically constructed for a bipartite graph?

Comment: @user3150601 an adjacency list is defined for any graph not just for a bipartite graph. It is one of the possible ways to represent a graph in the computer.

Comment: Do you understand what NIL is? Specifically something like Dist[NIL]?

Comment: NIL is an artificial node the author adds and uses in a special manner.

Comment: I still don't understand what this means. What is Dist[NIL]? How would you code such an "artificial node" and how does it ever change to satisfy the condition that Dist[NIL] != ∞?